# Python Pandas Dataframe enrichment (from another)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I would like to enrich a dataframe (df1) from another(df2) by adding a new column in df1 and enriching it based on what I find in df2. The size of the 2 df is different as well as the name of the columns. I would like to do like a Vlookup function in Excel.

This what I've done but I think there is a way to optimize it :

```
import pandas as pd  
df1 = pd.read_csv(xxx)  
df2 = pd.read_csv(xxx)  
df1["Enrich"] = ""  
for index_1 , row_1 in df1.iterrows():  
    for index_2,row_2 in df2.iterrows():  
      if df1.loc[index_1,"filter_1"] == df2.loc[index_2,"filter_2"]:  
         df1.loc[index_1,"Enrich"] == df2.loc[index_2,"Theneededvalue"]
```

Thanks for your help !

JaNa

Comment: Please take a while to read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample it's hard to help but vlookup can be implemented like that:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='filter1', right_on='filter2', how='left')
```